# ¿Cómo puedo hacer fuera de red local a mi scritp chat para chatear con otro usuario?

Tags: bash

lo hice de esta manera quiero compartirlo mi script de fuera red local para poder chatear  con otro usuario `ssh -R $pueto:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run &> /dev/null` Nose , si asi es la manera ?

```
#!/bin/bash 
#Colours                                                                                                  
greenColour="\e[0;32m\033[1m"                                                                             
endColour="\033[0m\e[0m" 
redColour="\e[0;31m\033[1m"                                                                               
blueColour="\e[0;34m\033[1m" 
yellowColour="\e[0;33m\033[1m" 
purpleColour="\e[0;35m\033[1m" 
turquoiseColour="\e[0;36m\033[1m " 
grayColour="\e[0;37m\033[1m"

echo -n "Ingres un puerto: "; read puerto 
ssh -R $pueto:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run &> /dev/null
clear                                                                                                     
echo -e "$greenColour" echo -n -e "Intruduce el nombre de usuario:$endColour$blueColour "                                        
read USER                                                                                                 
echo -e "$endColour"                                                                                      
echo -e "$blueColour[$(date +' Hora:%l:%M:%S')]$endColour $redColour${USER}$yellowColour se unió al chat$endColourd\n" | tee -a chat.log 2>/dev/null                                                                echo -e "$blueColour[$(date +'Hora:%l:%M:%S')]$endColpur $yellowColour¡Bievanido al Chat! $endColour${USER}$endColour$yellowColour!$endColour\n" 
tail -n 0 -f chat.log --pid=$$ 2>/dev/null | grep  --line-buffered -v "]${USER}>" &  
while read mensaje 
do         
echo -e "[$(date +'Hora:%l:%M:%S')]${USER}> ${mensaje}" >> chat.log 2>/dev/null 
done
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "sea fuera de la red local con lolcalhost.run"? Además de un título, sería bueno que incluyeras una explicación de tu problema, además de un  [mcve]. Un script entero no ayuda a entender el problema, seguro que hay mucho superfluo

Comment: Ya lo acomode mi amor , muchas gracias ante mano